# How can i get the correct information to display in my listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, listbox

I have two Listboxes where you can move exercises from an available list of exercises to a list of selected exercises for a specific user.  My current problem is that my selected list (aka RegimeItems) shows the exercises for all of the users.

I believe the problem lies in ChosenExercises(at the bottom of controller) i am also getting a **null reference exception** at:

`var regimeIDs = model.SavedRequested.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));`

**Controller.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(int? id, UserExerciseViewModel vmodel)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                user.RegimeItems = ChosenExercises();
                UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = ChosenExercises(user, vmodel) };
                user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
                return View(model);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;;
                RestoreSavedState(model);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
                    AddExercises(model, id);
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))
                    RemoveExercises(model, id);        
                SaveState(model);
                return View(model);
            }

            void SaveState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
            {
                model.SavedRequested = string.Join(",", model.RequestedExercises.Select(p => p.RegimeItemID.ToString()).ToArray());
                model.AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises().ToList();
            }

            void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
            {
                model.RequestedExercises = new List<RegimeItem>();

                //get the previously stored items
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
                {
                    string[] exIds = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
                    var exercises = GetAllExercises().Where(p => exIds.Contains(p.ExerciseID.ToString()));
                    model.AvailableExercises.AddRange(exercises);
                }
            }

            private List<Exercise> GetAllExercises()
            {
                return db.Exercises.ToList();
            }

            private List<RegimeItem> ChosenExercises(User user, UserExerciseViewModel model)//RegimeItem regimeItem)
            {
var regimeIDs = model.SavedRequested.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));
            return db.RegimeItems.Where(e => regimeIDs.Contains(e.RegimeItemID)).ToList();
            //return db.Users.Where(r => r.RegimeItems = user.UserID);
            //return db.Users.Where(r => r.RegimeItems.RegimeItemID == user.UserID);
            }
```

**Models**

```
  public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            this.RegimeItems = new List<RegimeItem>();
        } 
    }
    public class RegimeItem
    {
        public int RegimeItemID { get; set; }
        public Exercise RegimeExercise { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class UserExerciseViewModel
{
    public List<Exercise> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
    public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedExercise { get; set; }
    public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
    public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
return db.Users.Where(r => r.RegimeItems = user.UserID);
```

to

```
return db.Users.Where(r => r.RegimeItems.RegimeItemID == user.UserID);
```

Because the way I read it you're currently trying to match an int with an object.

edit: Another error was resulted which the OP found himself.

"It seems that RegimeItems is a collection of RegimeItem - it does not have a have a single ID. So it needed to be .Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID) and then to select the regimeItems associated with the user .SelectMany(u => u.RegimeItems).ToList(); Thanks for your help, if you update your answer with that i will mark yours as the correct answer." -Nilmag

Comment: Thankyou Peter, a strange error has occurred now it's telling me that `Model.RegimeItem does not contain a definition for RegimeItemID` which is odd because it most definitely does.

Comment: Does it have something to do with `public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }` in the Model?

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to see if the model is properly transferred?

Comment: It seems that RegimeItems is a collection of RegimeItem - it does not have  a have a single ID. So it needed to be `.Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID)` and then to select the regimeItems associated with the user `.SelectMany(u => u.RegimeItems).ToList();`  Thanks for your help, if you update your answer with that i will mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: I'll edit in that you found the rest yourself and you can mark it as you wish :) Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're going to want to update the calls to `ChosenExercises()` in `ExcerciseIndex(int? id)` to pass in the user like this: `ChosenExercises(user)`.

Secondly, the conversion error is because you are comparing `r.RegimeItems` to the User ID, which is an int. In order to return a list of regime items for the user you'll need to query the Excercises table, rather than the users table:

```
private List<RegimeItem> ChosenExercises(User user)//RegimeItem regimeItem)//User user, RegimeItem regimeItem)
{
  var regimeIDs = user.SavedRequested.Split(',').Select(x=>int.Parse(x));
  return db.RegimeItem.Where(e=> regimeIDs.Contains(e.RegimeItemID)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, `SavedRequest` is not in user it is in the viewmodel so i added that into the the variable as `model`. i am getting another error on the second line of code which is : `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Model.Exercise>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.RegimeItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: I believe it should be `return db.RegimeItems.Where(e => regimeIDs.Contains(e.RegimeItemID));` as the exercises are what go into regimeitems. However im getting a similar error.

Comment: You're correct, it should be querying  `db.RegimeItem` and you'll need to add `.ToList()' to resovle the conversion error. Sorry about that! I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am now getting this error on the second line: `'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I have updated my question with the changes made so far.

Comment: Whoops, I added to the ToList() inside the where rather than outside it. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting this error now at `ChosenExercises(user)` in the index post request `No overload for method 'ChosenExercises' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: You've updated the method to have two parameters, so you'll need to pass both everytime you try to call it.

Comment: I tried using `(model, user)` but now im getting `Cannot convert viewmodel to User` and vice versa.

Comment: Aswell as `The best overloaded method match for 'Controller.ChosenExercises(Model.User, Models.UserExerciseViewModel)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: The order of the parameters matters, so you need to send them in the same order as in the method definition.

Comment: Ah that would make sense, its now telling me `Use of unassigned local variable 'model'`

Comment: Nevermind i think i fixed it, i just added a vmodel into the index parameter of the same viewmodel. I'll test it now.

Comment: I am getting a null reference exception on `var regimeIDs = model.SavedRequested.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));` in ChosenExercises.  Is it because of `var regimeIDs`? from what im reading it hasnt referenced the RegimeItem model.